# batch file find to parse out keywords

Tags: batch-file, find, text-files

I have a list of words stored in a text file called blacklist.txt  I want to go through output from another program and take out all the lines that contain any of these words.

if i do this:

```
for /f %%G in (blacklist.txt) find /v /i "%%G" output.txt > newoutput.txt
```

I only get the results form the last find

if i do this:

```
for /f %%G in (blacklist.txt) find /v /i "%%G" output.txt > output.txt
```

I would expect it to update the file and run the next find on it systematically filtering out all the blacklisted strings.  This however is not the case and the file becomes blank after the second find is run on it...

Has anyone tried doing something similar to this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%g in (blacklist.txt) do (
    find /v /i "%1" <output.txt >tmp
    move tmp output.txt
)
```

Note that getting `find` to read from stdin means you won't get spurious `---------- output.txt` lines appearing in the output.

Comment: that's pretty sleek too I'm gonna give that a go after I do a test run of the whole process I'm trying to do.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I mean.  Put following in a batch file and run it:

```
for /f %%G in (blacklist.txt) do call :finder %%G
goto :EOF

:finder
find /v /i "%1" output.txt > output.tmp
copy output.tmp output.txt
```

The output.txt will contain non-matching lines.  It will also contain multiple times the name of the input file.  To avoid this, you can use the findstr instead of find command.

Comment: You don't have to switch from `find`. Use redirection of input: `find /v /i "%1" <output.txt > output.tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to the file, change `>` to `>>`. Also, remove the space before the file name.

```
for /f %%G in (blacklist.txt) find /v /i "%%G" output.txt >>newoutput.txt
```

Comment: the problem is I want it to overwrite the file after each find so that I end up with only the lines from output.txt that don't contain ANY of the strings in blacklist.txt...if i append it I end up with all the different find results in one file and a bigger list than i started with

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. I note `findstr` has both `/v` and `/g:file`. This means that you can forget about the for loop.

```
findstr /v /l /g:blacklist.txt output.txt >tmp
move tmp output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

use >> instead of >
Just don't forget to remove the output file for a second run, >> will always append to an existing file
And you cannot redirect to the same file as the input, this is not support in a cmd.exe under windows

Comment: because I'm doing a not find appending to a file just ends up listing almost everything in output.txt multiple times....but knowing that i cant redirect to the same file as input explains why I'm getting a blank file...there has to be some way to keep making my list smaller as I edit out each blacklisted word.

Comment: How about using a 'call' statement in the 'for', and in the called block you do the find to a temp file and then move the temp file to the input file, so the next iteration operates on the result of the previous one.  (and yes, I pressed the return key to quickly...)

Comment: yeah...sorry, had to obfuscate my question a bit otherwise its no fun. :p  But that worked thanks for the help!!...now i just need to find out how to make find not write the name of the file its searching at the top of the file every time...

Comment: Side note: Unix doesn't support it either. It's generally a bad idea to overwrite the input file.

Comment: unless you know what you're doing ;)

Comment: @Milque: No, not even then. Since the file isn't read and then processed but both happen simultaneously you're just destroying your data while you read it.